# angular 4 http interceptor: Factory not getting called

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-providers

I am trying to add interceptor to my angular 4 app.

I have following interceptor code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConnectionBackend, Headers, Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[ConnectionBackend], [RequestOptions]];
    }
    constructor(private backend: ConnectionBackend,
        private defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, options));
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        return options;
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        debugger;
        //this.events.publish("httpInterceptor:request:initiated");
        return observable
            .do((res: Response) => {
                //this.events.publish("httpInterceptor:request:success");
            }, (err: any) => {
                //this.events.publish("httpInterceptor:request:failure", err);
            });
    }
}

export function HttpInterceptor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    debugger;
    return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions);
}
```

And I am using in app.module as following

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    SpinnerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpEventHandler,
    XHRBackend,
    {
  provide: Http, useFactory: (xhrbackend, requestoptions, HttpEventHandler) => {
    return new CustomHttp(xhrbackend, requestoptions, HttpEventHandler);
  }, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HttpEventHandler]
},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, SpinnerComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Following are the versions of modules I am using

```
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
```

But none of the debugger statement is getting hit. Can some one help me out here? And if I inject it into any component it is showing error as "no provider for connectionbackend". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using HttpClient introduced in Angular 4.3 that supports interceptors?

Comment: @YakovFain Yes I can try that. But since there will be at least 15 peoples working on this project I do not want to upgrade and create chaos. Anyways I will move to it but wanted to know what is causing this issue.

Comment: Upgrading from using Http to HttpClient is easy. In the existing code just inject HttpClient instead of Http and remove res.json() from the existing subscriptions.IMO, this approach is cleaner.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot @YakovFain I am moving to HttpClient I did not know that it existed. And I do not know why I changed the usefactory callback to{
      provide: Http, useFactory: (xhrbackend, requestoptions) => {
        debugger;
        return new CustomHttp(xhrbackend, requestoptions);
      }, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }, It worked fine.

Comment: your app module says nothing about CustomHttp

Comment: @Ignasi sorry I was trying different things and pasted that code here. Updated the code

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this: http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

Answer (score 0):

With angular 4.3 here is the reference :- https://angular.io/guide/http

With current  implementation use 
`providers: [
    HttpEventHandler,
    XHRBackend,
    CustomHttp,
    {
  provide: Http, useFactory: HttpInterceptor, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HttpEventHandler]
},
  ],`